# PVLIB: Problems to calculate the hour angle using PVLIB

Tags: python, pvlib

I'm trying to calculate the hour angle for using the PVLIB's function "**pvl.solarposition.hour_angle()**".

The code that I'm developing is structured in 02 parts:

- First I'm transforming GPS time (seconds of week) in UTC Time formated in '**%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'**. The result obtained here is in UTC time because the GPS time is refering in UTC.
- On second part I try to calculate the hour angle using PVLIB and on this part I'm having problems.

When I'll run the hour angle the python is returning the an error message:

**"naive_times = times.tz_localize(None) # naive but still localized
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tz_localize".**

I know that this erros is about the class for variable "final_time" on the code implemented. According the PVLIB documentation this variable is need stay on class **pandas.DatetimeIndex** (https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pvlib.solarposition.hour_angle.html) and I dont know transform correctly the GPS time to this class and then, use this result on the PVLIB to compute the hour angle.

Bellow follow part of algorithm that I'm using here on the tests:

```py
import datetime
import pvlib as pvl


t_gps = 138088.886582 #seconds of week

lat = -23.048576 # degress
long = -46.305043 # degrees


## Transfomring the GPS time (seconds of week) in Date Time

## The result printed here is in UTC time because the GPS time is refered in UTC Time.

datetimeformat = ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
leapsecond = 37
epoch = datetime.datetime.strptime ( "1980-01-06 00:00:00" , datetimeformat)
decorrido = datetime.timedelta( days = (2024 * 7 ), seconds = t_gps + leapsecond)
final_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(epoch + decorrido, datetimeformat)
print(final_time)
print(type(final_time))

## Calculating the hour angle using PVLIB

solar_declin = pvl.solarposition.declination_spencer71(295)
print(solar_declin)

eq_time = pvl.solarposition.equation_of_time_pvcdrom(295)
print(eq_time)

hour_angle = pvl.solarposition.hour_angle(final_time, long, eq_time)
print(hour_angle)
```

For this problem my questions are:

1. How may I transform GPS time (seconds of week) to the format '**%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'** and on the class **pandas.DatetimeIndex**?

   2. How the result after the GPS time transformation is in UTC time, I need convert to the local time first and transform again for UTC time including the tz_localize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my approach i use [astropy](https://www.astropy.org/) library for converting gps time into date time format. Next convert this time to [Datetimeindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) with pandas;

=^..^=

```
import pandas as pd
import pvlib as pvl
from astropy.time import Time

latitude = -23.048576 # degress
longitude = -46.305043 # degrees

# convert gps seconds to time format
gps_time = 138088.886582
t = Time(gps_time, format='gps')
t = Time(t, format='iso')

# create empty df
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Timestamp'])

# create date time series
time_series = pd.to_datetime(str(t), infer_datetime_format=True)

# append time series to data frame
df = df.append({'Timestamp': pd.to_datetime(time_series)}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'Timestamp': pd.to_datetime(time_series)}, ignore_index=True)

# create time index
time_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Timestamp)

# calculate hour angle
hour_angle = pvl.solarposition.hour_angle(time_index, longitude, latitude*60)
```

Output:

```
[-356.58415383 -356.58415383]
```

Comment: Zaraki Kenpachi, thank you for help me with the solution. It solved my problem and now is possible to calculate the hour angle but has a little problem on the date calculated when the code converts the gps seconds for a time format. The correct date is 2018-10-22 and the value that is printed is 1980-01-07. Do you have any ideia to convert to correct date (2018-10-22)?

Comment: @CésardePaula the data is calculated correctly. According to https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.time.TimeGPS.html#astropy.time.Time GPS in seconds is added to 1980-01-06 00:00:00 UTC date,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `datetime` or strings to fill your `DatetimeIndex`, create `pandas.Timestamp`, the `pandas` version of `datetime.datetime`.

First build a Posix timestamp, aka seconds from epoch:

```
week_number = 2024
t_gps = 138088.886582
leapsecond = 37
posix_ts = week_number * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 + t_gps + leapsecond
```

Then build a `Timestamp`:

```
pandas_ts = Timestamp.utcfromtimestamp(posix_ts)
>>> Timestamp('2008-10-17 14:22:05.886582')
```

At this point, the `Timestamp` is "naive": while build as UTC, it does not contain time zone information, so:

```
pandas_ts = pandas_ts.tz_localize("UTC")
>>> Timestamp('2008-10-17 14:22:05.886582+0000', tz='UTC')
```

Finally, you can convert to your local time zone:

```
pandas_ts = pandas_ts.tz_convert("my_time_zone")  # replace by correct tz
>>> Timestamp('2008-10-17 NN:22:05.886582+XXXX', tz='my_time_zone')
```

and build the required `DatetimeIndex`:

```
di = DatetimeIndex([pandas_ts])
print(di)  # shows the time zone in the type (dtype='datetime64[ns, my_time_zone]')

long = -46.305043
eq_time = pvl.solarposition.equation_of_time_pvcdrom(295)
hour_angle = pvl.solarposition.hour_angle(di, long, eq_time)
print(hour_angle)
```

Don't mix `tz_localize` and `tz_convert` and remember to always set the timezone. This way you control the creation of the `DatetimeIndex`, using string you rely on the automatic parsing by `pandas`, problematic with time zone.

Comment: gaFF, thank you for help me. Now I understood about the problem and the solution who you suggested here solved the problem and now is possible to calculate the hour angle. As I commented above, your suggestion has a probelm on the date. The correct date is 2018-10-22 and in your solution suggested, the date that is printed is 2009-02-20. Do you have any idea to obtain the correct date?

Comment: The problem comes from an incorrect week number. We have no details in your sample code to help you, but you have to find a reliable way to translate the week indication to a number of day from epoch. I took `2024 * 7` from your code.

Comment: Ok....I used this website to calculate the week number https://www.labsat.co.uk/index.php/en/gps-time-calculator and I see that isn't correct. Do you suggest another way to determine the correct week number?

Comment: What is your initial information ? The week number is not the goal, the goal is the number of days from 1st January 1970.